# Data is null when trying to add auto generated document ID from firebase to object. Why?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm streaming a collection from firebase and I want to add the auto generated ID into ProductModel object.

```
Stream<List<ProductModel>> getprod() {
    return _firestore
        .collection('macarons')
        .snapshots()
        .map((QuerySnapshot query) {
      List<ProductModel> retVal = [];
      query.docs.forEach((element) {
        retVal.add(ProductModel.fromJson(element.data(), element.id));
        print(element.id);
      });
      return retVal;
    });
  }
```

This is my model

```
ProductModel.fromJson(
    Map<String, dynamic> prod,
    String id,
  ) {
    id = id;
    description = prod['description'] ?? 'Classic macaron';
    flavor = prod['flavor'] ?? 'Choclate';
    name = prod["name"] ?? 'empty';
    price = prod["price"] ?? 5;
    imageurl = prod["imageurl"] ?? 'www.google.com';
  }
```

I do get the ID printed out however it is not rendering on my widget. I get the 'data != null' assertion.

Comment: `this.id = id;`, since otherwise the left-hand side of the expression might also be interpreted as the parameter and thus the assignment becomes a noop?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in:

```
id = id;
```

The left-hand side of the expression is also interpreted as the `id` parameter, so the assignment becomes a noop.

You'll want to do this instead:

```
this.id = id;
```